# How to find the vector equation of the line segment.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, line-integrals

Let $C$ be the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$, and let $f(x,y)=x^2+y$.

Write down a vector equation $r(t)$ of the line segment, that is, find a parametrization of $C$.

The answer given is $r(t)=\langle t,t\rangle,0\le t\le 2$.

**My Question: How did they get $\boldsymbol{r(t)=\langle t,t\rangle}$?**

Comment: What does $f$ have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

The line going from $(0, 0)$ to $(2, 2)$ has equation $y = x$, so a parametrization could be

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& t \\
y(t) &=& x(t) = t
\end{eqnarray}

For $0 \leq t \leq 2$ a parametrization of $C$ is

$$
{\bf r}(t) = (t, t)~~~\mbox{for}~~ 0\leq t \leq 2
$$

Answer (score 0):

A (non-uniquely) parametrized straight line segment that goes from a startpoint $(x_0,y_0)$ to an endpoint $(x_1,y_1)$ is given in vector form as $$\langle x,y\rangle = \langle x_0,y_0\rangle +\lambda \langle x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0\rangle, \qquad 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1.$$ After plugging in your numbers, you end up with $\langle x,y\rangle = \lambda \langle 2,2\rangle = \langle 2\lambda,2\lambda\rangle$. Letting $t:=2\lambda$ gives the desired parametrization, but that last step is more of a personal choice.